# Android Studio - Breaking too deep

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new to Studio.  Crazy thing happening when I am debugging. I put a few breakpoints on my Fragments. When debugging it hits the breakpoints but then also breaks on lines in sdk source that I have not set. So when I step out, it lands on SDK code lines!!. I really don't want to crawl through all this, but step out just jumps to another SDK line.  Is this the default behavior? Does anyone know how to turn this off.

Comment: I've been really annoyed by this as well. Instead of stepping in, I just put break points on every line of code I'm interested in and use f9 (resume) to jump between them...avoiding going into the sdk. I'm really curious to see if anyone actually knows how to fix this too, but if not...you may want to use this workaround as well.

Comment: Yes, very strange default behavior for an IDE. I was using eclipse ADT for 4 years. Never anything like this.  Gradle support is cool though

Comment: actually f9 is cool.  Perhaps there should just be an extra button in studio that has step out really meaning to jump to next breakpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe what you want to do is possible. The debugger doesn't know the difference between *your* code and system/framework code. You can "step in", "step over", or " step out".

The latter brings you out of the current function call, up the stack frame, to the point where your function was called from. If you leave a callback or lifecycle function like onCreate() by "step out" or otherwise, you get to the caller of the function, which is somewhere in the system.

This is not specific to Android Studio either.

The only thing I can think of is what's said in a comment to your question as well, add breakpoints to the start of each function in your code and use "resume" once you hit system code.

I've created a simple sample `Activity` to illustrate what I'm talking about, and just to make sure we're talking about the same thing, since you're not supplying a specific example in your question:

The `Activity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "onClick"); // set breakpoint here
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The trivial layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.testuserpresent.MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="test" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I've tested this using Eclipse ADT and Android Studio:

1. Set a breakpoint on `Log.d()` in `onClick()`
2. Debug the app
3. Click the button
4. The app stops at the breakpoint
5. Click "Step return" or "Step out"
6. Source window for `View.class` / `View.java` from package `android.view` opens in a new window and debugging continues there

Hitting "Resume" in step 5. in either Eclipse ADT or Android Studio, resumes execution of the app and does not break in Android source code.

Does this example correctly represent what your asking in your question?

Comment: well, I can't say I remember this happening in eclipse during debugging.  I would remember that.

Comment: Thanks for following up.  All I can say is that I keep hitting step out and it goes deeper.  I thought step return step out would take me to the next breakpoint I set.    Sometime step return jumps to my next breakpoint and sometimes it just goes deeper in Android source.  Why would the assumption be that one wants to keep debugging into the View.class?  I mean I might just want to check some variables in onResume(), then jump to next breakpoint in another fragment or activity.  should be the default behavior of step out not to go and look deep into a view. SDK classes usu. ok.

Comment: well maybe its just that the resume option is not really handy in Android studio.

Comment: All I can say is that I just jumped on a project with Android studio and it was not clear to me how to move from breakpoint to breakpoint.  I would like to be able to stay in studio and not do f9's or whatever at the same time.

Comment: Step out/return steps out of the current function and continues debugging the caller of that function. Always. In every debugger I know. When that caller is also your code, you continue debugging your code, when that caller is SDK code, then you continue debugging that. If you want to resume execution until you hit the next breakpoint, you hit resume/continue. I don't understand why your expectation would be that step out behaves the same way as resume. If they were the same we'd only need one. You see no point in what step out does? Don't use it, just use resume.

Comment: ok, well maybe the resume just needs to be more handy in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a MAC Alt-Cmd-R will goto next breakpoint.  Why there is no such debugger step in Android Studio is beyond me.  Please somebody lets fix this.

Comment: I still don't get what your issue is, maybe I have this all wrong. FWIW, "Resume program" will, surprise surprise, resume your program. It will then break at the next breakpoint it encounters. Can you show a specific example, with code, where this doesn't work for you?